# Amplify EAS Metro config migration blockList

Tags: react-native, expo, aws-amplify, expo-eas

When migrating to EAS, I was reading the [Migration Docs](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/migrating/#metroconfigjs--must-export-the-entire-default) and saw that EAS builds are requiring the entire `defaultConfig` from `expo/metro-config`. I was having a tough time looking into how to utilize this `mtro.config.js`...

```
const blacklist = require("metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList")

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/amplify\/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/]),
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
}
```

So that I will not get the `jest-haste-map` error for duplicate file names if adding a function or some other errors that may come with other.

With this code, some images are not included in the build, so the question is how to utilize `defaultConfig` and avoid the `jest-haste-map` issue?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to simply share my solution, and I'm aware that there are `expo build` projects that used some variants of this `metro.config.js` or `rn-cli.config.js` to appropriately configure the metro bundler.

```
const blacklist = require("metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList")

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/amplify\/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/]),
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
}
```

I wasn't able to find documentation on what the `const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname)` from `expo/metro-config` structure looks like (maybe someone can comment a link?) and just had to wing it. This worked for configuring the `blockList` (not the `blackListRE`) resolver and load my images appropriately:

****metro.config.js****

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push('db');
defaultConfig.resolver.blockList = [/amplify\/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/];

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

Per the [Migration Docs](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/migrating/#metroconfigjs--must-export-the-entire-default), this is the ideal way to append any custom config options to the `const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname)` object. And you can see that I am setting `blockList`, so any other files you need to block could also be set to this array.

Hope this helps the Amplify people!